# Java visitor return issue

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a section of code for a simple drawing program in java. I have a class called "fixtures" that has the code:

```
    public static final Shape simpleGroup = new Group(
       new Location(200, 100, new Circle(50)),
       new Location(400, 300, new Rectangle(100, 50))
    );

    public static final Shape middleGroup = new Location(50, 100,
       new Group(
         new Outline(new Rectangle(50, 30)),
         new Group(
     new Circle(20),
     new Rectangle(50, 30)
          )
       )
    );

    public static final Shape complexGroup = new Location(50, 100,
       new Group(
       new Circle(20),
       new Rectangle(100, 200),
       new Location(150, 50,
       new Stroke(Color.RED,
           new Fill(
           new Group(
              new Rectangle(50, 30),
              new Outline(new Rectangle(300, 60)),
              new Stroke(Color.CYAN,
                 new Polygon(
                    new Point(50, 50),
                    new Point(60, 100),
                    new Point(100, 110),
                    new Point(120, 60)
                 )
              ),
              new Location(100, 200,
                 new Stroke(Color.MAGENTA,
                    new Outline(new Circle(50))
                 )
              )
           )
        )
     )
  )
 )
);
```

I then have a class called "size" that is supposed to count the number of objects in fixtures. I have a test class that asserts that groupsimple returns 2, groupmiddle returns 3, and groupcomplex returns 6. I am supposed to fix the size code, but I cannot figure it out.

```
@Override
public Integer onGroup(final Group g) {
   return null;
}
```

The group class's code:

```
public class Group implements Shape {

   protected final List<? extends Shape> shapes;

   public Group(final Shape... shapes) {
      this.shapes = Arrays.asList(shapes);
   }

   public List<? extends Shape> getShapes() {
      return Collections.unmodifiableList(shapes);
   }

   @Override
   public <Result> Result accept(final Visitor<Result> v) {

      return v.onGroup(this);
   }
```

There are more classes involved, but I think this should be enough to show my point. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

A bit unclear, because you didn't tell what the visitor was supposed to do exactly, and why the size of groupcomplex is 6 for example. But I guess all you want is something like this:

```
@Override
public Integer onGroup(Group g) {
   int count = 0;
   for (Shape shape: g.getShapes()) {
       count += shape.accept(this);
   }
   return count;
}

@Override
public Integer onRectangle(Rectangle r) {
    return 1;
}

// same for other shapes
```